# My animations crash on device but not in simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, animation

Hi im a noob trying to put together an iPad app. All runs smoothly on simulator but not on device. I have five view controllers and it is the fifth one that chrashes especially when running the monster animation.

Im posting the code here from that view controller. Please don't laugh.

It also says it received memory warning. Whats up with that?

Thank you anybody.

```
import "FifthViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"



@interface FifthViewController ()

@end

@implementation FifthViewController


@synthesize doorImage;

@synthesize flagImage;

@synthesize kuckuImage;

@synthesize treImage;

@synthesize moppImage;


-(IBAction)trollljud:(id)sender{ 
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle(); 
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef; 
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"trolleri3", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID; 
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID); 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); 
    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef); }

-(IBAction)monsterljud:(id)sender{ 
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle(); 
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef; 
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Monsterljud", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID; 
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID); 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); 
    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef); }

-(IBAction)dorrljud:(id)sender{ 
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle(); 
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef; 
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"dörrljud", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID; 
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID); 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); 
    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef); }

-(IBAction)kuckuljud:(id)sender{ 
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle(); 
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef; 
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Fun24", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL); 
    UInt32 soundID; 
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID); 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); 
    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef); }

-(IBAction)flaggljud:(id)sender{ 
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle(); 
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef; 
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Flag1", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL); 
    UInt32 soundID; 
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID); 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); 
    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef); }

-(IBAction)change:(id)sender{
    ViewController *two = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    two.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:two  animated:YES];
    [theAudio stop];
    [two release];

}


-(IBAction)hideButton

{
    Button2.hidden=FALSE; }

-(IBAction)hideButton2

{
    Button3.hidden=TRUE; }


- (void) openDoor {
    [doorImage startAnimating]; }

- (void) kucku {
    [kuckuImage startAnimating]; }

- (void) flag {
    [flagImage startAnimating]; }

- (void) tre {
    [treImage startAnimating]; }

- (void) mopp {
    [moppImage startAnimating]; }


-(IBAction)oneFingerSwipeLeft:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle(); 
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef; 
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Droid2", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL); 
    UInt32 soundID; 
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID); 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); 
    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef);
     }

-(IBAction)oneFingerSwipeRight:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle(); 
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef; 
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Droid", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL); 
    UInt32 soundID; 
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID); 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); 
    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef);
     }

-(IBAction)oneFingerSwipeUp:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle(); 
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef; 
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Wolf2", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL); 
    UInt32 soundID; 
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID); 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); 
    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef);
     }

-(IBAction)oneFingerSwipeDown:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle(); 
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef; 
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Snake2", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL); 
    UInt32 soundID; 
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID); 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); 
    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef);
     }



- (void)viewDidLoad{

    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeLeft = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                                         initWithTarget:self 
                                                         action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeLeft:)] autorelease];
        [oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
        [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeLeft];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeRight = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                                          initWithTarget:self 
                                                          action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeRight:)] autorelease];
        [oneFingerSwipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
        [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeRight];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeUp = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                                       initWithTarget:self 
                                                       action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeUp:)] autorelease];
        [oneFingerSwipeUp setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
        [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeUp];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeDown = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                                         initWithTarget:self 
                                                         action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeDown:)] autorelease];
        [oneFingerSwipeDown setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
        [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeDown];



    }


    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [Button2 setHidden:TRUE];
    }

    {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Okenljud" ofType:@"mp3"];
        if (theAudio) [theAudio release];
        {
            theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
            [theAudio play];
            theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
        }
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSArray *doorFrames = [NSArray array];
        doorFrames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"dörr51.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"dörr51.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"dörr52.png"],          
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"dörr53.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"dörr54.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"dörr55.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"dörr56.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"dörr57.png"], Nil];
        doorImage.animationImages = doorFrames;
        doorImage.animationDuration = 3;
        doorImage.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    }


    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSArray *kuckuFrames = [NSArray array];
        kuckuFrames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Kuckuhh1.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Kuckuhh2.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Kuckuhh3.png"],          
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Kuckuhh2.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Kuckuhh1.png"], Nil];
        kuckuImage.animationImages = kuckuFrames;
        kuckuImage.animationDuration = 1;
        kuckuImage.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    }

    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSArray *moppFrames = [NSArray array];
        moppFrames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m1.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m2.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m3.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"monster15.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"monster16.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"monster17.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m4.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"monster18.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"monster19.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m5.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m6.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m7.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m8.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m9.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m10.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m11.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m12.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m13.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"m14.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"monster20.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"monster21.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"monster22.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"monster23.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"monster24.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"monster25.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"monster26.png"], Nil];
        moppImage.animationImages = moppFrames;
        moppImage.animationDuration = 19;
        moppImage.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    }


    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSArray *fagelBilder = [NSArray array];
        fagelBilder = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"13.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"14.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"15.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"19.png"], 
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"20.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"21.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"22.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"23.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"24.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"25.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"26.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"27.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"28.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"29.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"30.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"31.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"32.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"33.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"38.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"14.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"13.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], Nil];
        treImage.animationImages = fagelBilder;
        treImage.animationDuration = 10;
        treImage.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    }

    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSArray *flagbilder = [NSArray array];
        flagbilder = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"F1.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f2.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f3.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f4.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f5.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f6.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f7.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f8.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f9.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f10.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f11.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f12.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f13.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f14.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f15.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f16.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f17.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f18.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f19.png"], 
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f20.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f21.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f20.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f22.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f20.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f23.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f20.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f22.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f20.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f23.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f20.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f22.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f20.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f23.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f20.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f24.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f25.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f26.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f27.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f28.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f29.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f30.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f31.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f32.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f33.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f34.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f35.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f36.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f37.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"f38.png"], Nil];
        flagImage.animationImages = flagbilder;
        flagImage.animationDuration = 15;
        flagImage.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    }


}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil; }

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft); }

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get memory warnings probably the app is not crashing but is being killed for excessive memory usage.

You can have memory leaks somewhere in your class or just demanding too much to that device.

Your class is very long so I cannot dig into it searching for the leak. But within Xcode there's a feature to automatically analyze your code for problems.

Just select from the menus: **Product** -> **Analyze**.

You'll receive a list of possible problems, just check every one for unreleased objects.

Comment: Ok, thank you MacTeo. When i Analyze the project i get two warnings in AppDelegate.m. Here:- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

} It seems like I have a problem with switching views. Do you know how I can solve it? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong there. Could you tell me the lines and the warnings you get?

Answer (score 0):

You have a memory problem. The simulator has the full memory resources of your computer which is much more than any iPhone or iPad.

It looks like you are trying to load way too many images at once. You may need to use smaller inages Or fewer images or change your animation method to a more on-demand type.

Also an more minor point.  For repetitive code like you have, use a "for" statement and "stringWithFormat".  It would knock it down to a couple lines.